# rmarkdown site generator workflow

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, blogdown

I'm working with an rmarkdown site generator comprised of 30 `*.Rmd` and facing a number of issues.

- Rendering the entire site takes a long time (~20-30 min) even with `cache=TRUE` in most chunks
- Some of the R generated figures are mismatched especially when `plotly` graphs are used (naming my chunks seems to help)
- Managing package requirements is becoming tedious (every `*.Rmd` has its own package requirements)
- Some `*.Rmd` require being connected to a VPN to query a database
- One `*.Rmd` requires running on a different machine because of [SSL issue with the OS](https://github.com/ropensci/weathercan/issues/104)

**Are there any common wisdom or suggestions on how to improve this workflow?** Any robust rmarkdown generated site on GitHub I can emulate?

Comment: benchmark which part takes so long... optimize (maybe cache) that part... rinse repeat..